# What is the formalism for a map that returns the adjacent vertex positions of a given adjacency matrix?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry, graph-theory

How do I formally denote a map that returns the adjacent vertex positions of a given adjacency matrix?

Example:

V = undirected adjacency matrix

$$ V =
\left[
\begin{matrix}
v_{1,1} &  v_{1,2}  & \ldots & v_{1,n}\\
v_{2,1}  &  v_{2,2} & \ldots & v_{2,n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
v_{m,1}  &   v_{m,2}       &\ldots & v_{m,n}
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
Let  $$
f_s(j,m) = \sum_{i = 1}^m(v_{i,j})
$$
such that
  $$ 
v_{i,j} \in \{0,1\} : i \in M=\{1,2,...,m\} , j \in N=\{1,2,...,n\} 
$$
and
  $$
\forall j \in N|2 \leq f_s(j,m)\leq m 
$$
(meaning that all vertices are adjacent at least one other vertex)
and

where
  $$
m = n
$$
 Thus, 
  $$ M = N \Rightarrow |M| = |N| \Rightarrow m = n
$$ (where |X| represents cardinality for the given set X) because 
  $$ M \subseteq N 
$$ and 
  $$ N \subseteq M 
$$
Let
  $$
S = M \Rightarrow S = N
$$
  $$
|S| = s \Rightarrow [s=m=n]
$$
Let
  $$ K \subset S : 2 \leq |K| \leq s
$$
(which will hold due to the sum above and the inequality below it).

$$
f_a : j \mapsto K
$$
Here's where I get stuck. I want $$ f_a $$ to be a map that aggregates the position values, the elements of N, where the corresponding position value is 1 for the corresponding row value. For example, if column 2 looks like this:
  $$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
0\\
1\\
1\\
0\\
1
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
  $$
a_{0,2} = 0, a_{1,2} = 1, a_{2,2} = 1, a_{3,2} = 0, a_{4,2} = 1 
$$
then I want the resulting output to be $$ f_a(2) = \{1,2,4\}$$.

How do I denote this? (i.e. What am I missing?) Also, feel free to comment on any notation that is not correct or is unconventional.